# Is there a way to control the ray length of a point light using an IES shader?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, lighting

Working in arch viz, I am using some ground spots and I've paired them with some point lights with and IES shader rotated upside down.
Now I have played with the radius and strength, but the issue is that it is emitting too much light in the ceiling and I am losing details.
I know light linking is in the process of being developed, but I was wondering if there is another way

Comment: you can change some parameters in the IES file, but from what I could see, that makes no real difference with changing the strength.